# SharePoint Overflow is dead, long live SharePoint.SE!

Tags: support, broken-link

It's been a while since SharePoint Overflow became [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/), but [this Google query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=sharepointoverflow.com%20site:stackoverflow.com&oq=sharepointoverflow.com%20site:stackoverflow.com) shows that there are still questions, answers and comments that refer the old site and all these links are dead - no redirect, no 404, no static page telling to go to SharePoint.SE, nothing.

I can edit the questions and the answers, I can flag the comments (though I'm not sure if I should), but wouldn't it be easier to automatically replace all the occurrences of `sharepointoverflow.com` with `sharepoint.stackexchange.com` in the database?

**Let me know how this problem will be handled** - will it be the regular *flag&edit* way or a few UPDATEs on the appropriate tables?

I wouldn't like to spend a few days correcting it manually just to learn that the remaining issues will be fixed automatically.

Comment: Sounds like a job for waffles... oh... :(

Comment: @Bolt maybe he ran out of maple! :P

Comment: After looking on google page 2 and more, I found what you mean. And beside inside comments, it is only a regex-stuff: change `sharepointoverflow` to `sharepoint.stackexchange` thats all.

Answer (score 3):

There will eventually be a tool for fixing broken links like this at https://stackoverflow.com/review/broken-links. But I think it's still in testing right now so the fix link/link works buttons don't do anything. In the future mass-fixing of broken links will be handled through that doohickey.

Comment: This tool will certainly be useful once it's ready, but I think in this case a one time operation performed by the administrators would be a better idea. Sometimes the reference is **not a clickable link** but a phrase like `SharePoint Overflow` or a domain mentioned in a comment .