# Confusion with domain names such as Superuser.SE, SU.SE and Sharepoint.SE

Tags: discussion, domain-names

Stack Exchange sites are often discussed with names ending in `.SE`. This happens to be the top-level domain name for Sweden, a very popular TLD locally. It's really bad when saying [SU.SE](http://su.se/) because that is one of the largest Swedish universities and the abbreviation of "Superuser" may not be apparent to everybody.

I have started to learn this now but I suspect new users may get confused. My suggestion is that we avoid saying `Superuser.SE` and similar to people at the SO site, especially to new users, but just use the correct name `Superuser.com` or `Superuser`.

It is hard to find examples from real comments, but here are some from Meta:

- [SharePoint Overflow is dead, long live SharePoint.SE!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137629/sharepoint-overflow-is-dead-long-live-sharepoint-se)
- [Why is Code Golf now the domain of Programmers.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/why-is-code-golf-now-the-domain-of-programmers-se?rq=1)

Comment: superuser.se: Made on a Mac, has only a couple of pictures, nothing else works. Figures.

Comment: I always felt it was obvious that the `.SE` shorthand was for on-site use only. I would never tell a potential new user about `Apple.SE` and would, actually, refer to it as [apple.se] in conversation.

Comment: Who even does that? It doesn't even make sense for Super User since that site has its own domain.

Comment: So basically you're saying "Stop using this slang!?"

Comment: Who uses .se when the footer says .com?

Comment: Robert, indeed, I am. And I'm also off to register the domain name "programmers.se" ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note, I think I could train myself to type Programmers-SE.  Would that satisfy your sensibilities?

Comment: aww... that'll kill the fun when the goats proposal takes off on Area51

Comment: @yoda I don't remember who anymore, but someone proposed that last April Fools.

Comment: @AdamLear It was one of the [judaism.se] mods...

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/can-stackoverflow-inc-purchase-the-se-top-level-domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we shorten Stack Exchange URLs by using .se domains?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69589/can-we-shorten-stack-exchange-urls-by-using-se-domains)

Comment: As an aside: Super User is written with a space.

Comment: It isn't `superuser.stackexchange.com`, it's just `superuser.com`, hence only referred to as `SU`. Don't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 4):

When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

It's pretty easy to realize that it's a shortform, IMO. You're on the Stack Exchange network. S. E. If someone says `programmers.SE`, it's pretty obvious that the SE means `stackexchange`. You've got to take the context of the term into account.

For example, on physics.stackexchange.com, if someone said "Physics.SE", it's pretty easy to know that they're talking about the site itself. If another site is mentioned, it's usually in the context of migration, so again it's obvious that it's another SE site. If someone is confused, s/he can always ask for clarification.

Note that nobody says SU.SE -- It's just abbreviated as SU. The same goes for SO (Stack Overflow), SF (Server Fault), and MSO (Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Also, don't use uppercase domain names. Hence Programmers.SE simply is not programmers.se.

Comment: How do you pronounce MSO? Is it like M-S-O or Meso?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I pronounce it Em Ess Oh. I think everyone does. Ess Oh, Ess Eff, Ess You, Em  Ess Oh, etc. Doesn't realy matter, feel free to pronounce it phonetically :)

Comment: This is really confusing. We all know that MSO means Malmö Symphony Orchestra, and they already have the domain registered [MSO.SE](http://www.mso.se). Context is everything!